# Check-box Value to be emailed

Tags: php, email, checkbox

I have a form that allows people to request a free eBook. The form details will be sent to an admin, upon return they will email the eBook to the user. I need to be able to show in this "system" email whether the user gave consent to be manually subscribed to the newsletter or not.

The checkbox is there, checked as the default state.

Here is the **system mail** I receive after submitting the form:

--

Name: Aniska

Surname: Berry

Email: nissberry@gmail.com

Residential: Ballito

Newsletter:

--

^As you can see the "Newsletter" value is empty - I need to be able to see here whether the user gave consent or not. (Whether the box was checked or not)

Here is my form:

```
<form method="POST" id="contact-form" class="form-inline" action="contactengine.php" onSubmit="alert('Thank you for your feedback!');">
    <div class="form-group white-text">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" class="form-control wow fadeInUp" placeholder="Name" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group white-text">
        <label>Surname</label>
        <input type="text" name="Surname" id="Surname" class="form-control wow fadeInUp" placeholder="Surname" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group white-text m-t">
        <label>Email address</label>
        <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" class="form-control wow fadeInUp" placeholder="Email" required/>
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group white-text m-t">
        <label>Residential Area</label>
        <input type="text" name="Residential" id="Residential" class="form-control wow fadeInUp" placeholder="Residential Area" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group checkbox white-text">
        <label>
            <input name="newsletter" type="checkbox" class="checked" checked>Consent
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group m-t m-b">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Please send me my EBook!" class="btn-primary wow fadeInUp" />
    </div>

</form>
```

And here is my php

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "admin@webmaster.com";
$EmailTo = "nissberry@gmail.com";
$Subject = "eBook request from User";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Surname = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Surname'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Residential = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Residential']));
$Newsletter = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Newsletter'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Surname: ";
$Body .= $Surname;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Residential: ";
$Body .= $Residential;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Newsletter: ";
$Body .= $Newsletter;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://www.remax-panache.co.za\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use check boxes that way. Use this way:

```
$Newsletter = isset($_POST['Newsletter']) ? true : false;
$Newsletter = isset($_POST['Newsletter']) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Either of the above should work. When you `POST` a check box, it posts using this way:

- Checked: `name=on`
- Unchecked: `(empty)` Doesn't post anything.

Comment: Thank you!
Would I replace $Newsletter = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Newsletter']));  with the line you provided above?

Comment: Hi @praveen the $Newsletter = isset($_POST['Newsletter']) ? "Yes" : "No"; works - it shows the value in the system mailer. However, whether it is checked or unchecked, it always shows "No" in the system mailer

Comment: @Nis Woah? Really? Always you get it as `No`? You are not clear.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. When I submit the form and "check" the box - the value in the system email = NO. When I submit the form and "uncheck" the box - the value in the system email = NO. So it doesn't matter whether the box has been checked or unchecked, it always returns NO in the system mailer

Comment: @Nis Can you explain what's happening now in your email? Are you getting `Yes / No` values for the `Newsletter`?

Comment: when I submit the form and check the box this is what I get: Name: A BERRY
Surname: BERRY
Email: nissberry@gmail.com
Residential: Ballito
Newsletter: No

Comment: could I be missing something in my html perhaps?

Comment: @Nis Yes! You are right. Case Sensitivity: `<input name="Newsletter" type="checkbox"`. Change it in the input tag please.